# Who should our moderators be?

Tags: discussion

I have received [word](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13040827#13040827) that the community managers are ready to pick moderators pro tem for Aviation.

With that in mind, I thought I'd ask anyone if they have any suggestions. Feel free to nominate yourself or someone else in a community wiki answer to this question.

---

> If your meta site does not have a post to nominate Moderators, start one now! Pro Tem appointments will begin about two weeks after the site is created. The more guidance we receive, the more informed our choice. [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)

- **Each nomination should be a separate answer**. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity.
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer, adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write something about themselves.
- Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.” Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.

We're looking for members of this site who:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

It's also good if the moderators:

- Are members with participation in both the meta and main site.
- Participated in Area 51, generate social network referrals, or blog about the site.
- Are members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

<sup>Lifted from the [meta.space](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60/moderator-nominations) nomination thread.</sup>

Answer (score 12):

Because he was too humble to nominate himself:

[image: profile for egid at Aviation Stack Exchange, Q&A for aircraft pilots, mechanics, and enthusiasts]

[profile for egid on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/987825.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/987825)

An active CFII and very active member of our community.

---

Thanks :) I accept the nomination. I was really excited to see this pop up on Area51! I hope to be able to help out however I can, moderator or not.

Comment: I was about to do it if he didn't! Seems you beat me to it.

Comment: I think egid would be an excellent moderator.  He's a level headed, tech-savvy, active pilot.   He knows his stuff, and cares about the community.

Answer (score 11):

I would like to nominate **lnafziger**.

[profile for lnafziger on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/901897.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/901897)

[image: profile for lnafziger at Aviation Stack Exchange, Q&A for aircraft pilots, mechanics, and enthusiasts]

lnafziger is an experienced Stack Exchange user, a professional commercial pilot, and has been dedicated to Aviation so far.

## Nomination Acceptance:

Thank you all for the nomination, I am **very** interested in helping to make this into a thriving community where we can all learn and help each other out!

I find that my engineering and maintenance background is very suitable for the Q&A format that we have here, and am always looking for the "correct" answer.  This also helps me with the maintenance/system side of aviation.  I have also been flying corporate jets for 10 years and am involved with managing a Part 135 charter certificate as the Assistant Chief Pilot.  This gives me a regulatory perspective that I think helps a lot in the aviation industry!

Comment: I second this nomination.

Answer (score 10):

I would like to nominate **voretaq7**.

[profile for voretaq7 on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/95292.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/95292)

[image: profile for lnafziger at Aviation Stack Exchange, Q&A for aircraft pilots, mechanics, and enthusiasts]

Voretaq7 is already an active member of other SE sites, and he has shown to be valuable to the growing Aviation community, his profile confirms that, too.

---

I'd be willing to fill the role as a pro-tem mod, though I'd also point out that we have a bunch of other excellent choices.

As far as moderation philosophy, so far the community here has been doing a great job of self-policing & deciding on site direction / early policy through constructive consensus, and I'd like to see that continue.
Particularly at these early stages I lean toward "Janitorial Moderation" - tweaking posts wth the occasional edit for clarity/formatting, mopping up obsolete comments, and nuking the occasional spammer (seriously - 20 days? How the heck do they find us so fast?!)
Most of the other stuff I prefer to see done through consensus on Meta as we've been doing - it's healthier for the site long-term, and it gives us a good set of ground rules & precedents as the site grows.

Comment: voretaq7 is also a moderator at Server Fault, so has moderating experience. IMHO, voretaq7 and Inafziger would make a good mix because of their different experience levels with moderating on SE.

Comment: As far as moderation philosophy, I don't think being a Server Fault mod is an asset - the charter of Server Fault ("by and for professionals") & the culture maintainin that charter is different from what I feel Aviation.SE needs as a site that's for people involved in aviation *and* curious outside enthusiasts (within reason).  That's particularly true in Beta, but I'd like to see it stay true as the site grows: A strong community here setting a good example for fresh blood might be able to make a small dent in the declining number of active pilots. End hopeless optimist rant.

Comment: @voretaq7 That you can recognize that makes you a good pick in my book.

Comment: @voretaq7 A lot of the moderation principles are still the same though, and you would be a great help to guide new moderators here because of your knowledge of SE.

Answer (score 7):

I nominate:

[image: profile for Otto the Autopilot at Aviation Stack Exchange, Q&A for aircraft pilots, mechanics, and enthusiasts]

...nah, I'm just kidding!! My vote goes to **all** of the guys above: @egid @lnafziger @voretaq7 - I think you'd all do a great job!

Comment: I am ***so*** tempted.

Comment: @TimPost we could add a routine to him to randomly delete posts and suspend users. Chaos Moderator! :)

Comment: Community user **so** needs to be renamed to Otto the Autopilot here

Answer (score 6):

I'm a bit late to the party but I'll see how it goes.

Though I certainly don't have the most experience on Stack Exchange sites amongst the nominees, nor am I as experienced in the aviation field as some of the others, I'd like to nominate myself to be a moderator for Aviation.

[image: profile for Qantas 94 Heavy on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

[profile for Qantas 94 Heavy on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/2052845.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/2052845)

I've been involved with the Aviation site since the following stage on Area 51, and have posted links to the site previously to help others interested in the aviation field to come and join this site ([an example](https://github.com/Qantas94Heavy/autopilot-pp/blob/master/README.md)).

On the site, I've contributed by asking numerous questions and answering other people's answers, as well as improving other people's posts, some of which is to improve spelling issues or to fix up the setting out of math formulas using `<sub>` and `<sup>` tags. When I'm trying to post something, I try my hardest to make sure that things are set out in a neat manner and that all of my answers are of the highest quality, such as ensuring that all posts are free from spelling and grammatical issues to a reasonable degree. If you'd like to see some of my contributions, you can take a look at [my Stack Exchange profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/2052845).

As well, I've had some experience on other Stack Exchange sites such as Stack Overflow, where I actively participate in community moderation, with over 6800 review completed and 1610 helpful flags (with a corresponding 60:1 helpful to declined ratio).

My activity on both Aviation's meta site and Meta Stack Overflow (the site for questions about the Stack Exchange network in general, as well as Stack Overflow) indicates my willingness to help out the community and put forward my opinions as to what we should be doing to improve the various sites out there.

I have also had some previous experience moderating [a low-volume forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gefs-online) for an online flight simulator, which I still currently do. Some of the challenges that have arose include dealing with users without offending them but still sending the message across, and trying to help organise events with the community to help out. Additionally, with the large number of "immature" people on the site, there is a large opportunity to have to interact with these users to check that they actually understand the rules of the site.

I'll be able to help out by ensuring that any menial tasks that need to get done are completed, that I'll be able to bring resolution to disputes in an effective manner, as well as maintaining my contributions to the Aviation community.

If you have any questions about anything that I've done or how I can help out, feel free to post a comment.

Answer (score 2):

After some deliberation on whether or not to wait til the next round of elections (since I think the other guys would do a great job), I'm nominating myself, because I'd also really like to be a mod if there are more than 3 positions:

[profile for Danny Beckett on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1703956.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/1703956)

[image: profile for Danny Beckett at Aviation Stack Exchange, Q&A for aircraft pilots, mechanics, and enthusiasts]

I'm regularly active in [The Hangar](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/the-hangar) and on the site, and I've been around Stack Exchange long enough to know my way around (with 986 helpful flags and 4,168 reviews on SO).

I mightn't be as knowledgeable in aviation as some of the other guys, but I'm very interested in it, and keen to learn.

Finally: I host and run the chat bot ([Otto the Autopilot](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/322/otto-the-autopilot)), and have written some [new commands](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156/what-would-you-like-the-chat-bot-to-do) for it, like:

```
!!weather JFK  !!metar JFK  !!taf JFK  !!teachmetofly
```