# What would you like the chat bot to do?

Tags: discussion, chat, bot

Firstly, if you haven't already dropped by [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/the-hangar) yet, do so! We're a very active bunch, and we don't bite!

In case you didn't know, we have a room bot, that you can currently get weather data from by typing `!!weather JFK`

[image]

Or you can get the standard METAR report with `!!metar LPL`

[image]

What other commands would people like to see? Please post a seperate answer for each one.

Answer (score 6):

A few of us were talking about this: an `!!airport` command to retrieve aerodrome data.

Comment: Would that list something like runway data, frequencies, etc.?

Comment: Exactly! :) @Qantas94Heavy

Comment: My 2 cents: Name, Location (Country/State/City), Elevation, Runway data (orientation/length), frequencies (ATIS, TWR/CTAF/UNICOM, Ground(?), & App/Dep(?)) -- maybe some other goodies like Landing Fee (Y/N)?

Answer (score 6):

`!!far <regulation number>`

Possibly the easiest way would be to download the XML file from the [eCFR website](http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/bulkdata/CFR) and parse it using XPath (or whatever we can use in Javascript) as needed.

> *Development Note*
>   The FARs can be searched by POSTing a form to `www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/searchECFR` with
>
> - `ob=r` ("Order by Relevance")
> - `idno=14` ("Search part 14")
> - Either of the following:
>
>   - `r=SECNBR` & `q1=part.section` (eg. `61.1`), or
>   - `r=PARTNBR` & `q1=part` (eg. `61`)
>
> (Parsing of the HTML returned is left as an exercise for the reader...)

and

`!!aim <paragraph number>`

Comment: Great suggestion, it's a shame that the official FAR and AIM pages aren't exactly link-friendly

Comment: Most likely you'd have to crawl the FARs for the relevant parts. Also, some parts are too big for the chat.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy We can truncate them at 500 chars, with a link to the full FAR.

Comment: Actually, we can send unformatted text with more than 500 characters (and it automatically includes a "more" link to keep it short for people that aren't interested).

Answer (score 6):

From an actual use case just now:

`!!ntsb N123AB`

Search the NTSB database ([CSV file](http://www.ntsb.gov/aviationquery/download.ashx?type=csv)) for a particular tail number, or various other parameters.

Comment: Great idea; I like it!

Answer (score 3):

Have you included an `!!atis` command yet?

Comment: Actually, what would you want this to do? Generally actual atis data is voice only, unless you're logged in to fboweb or something.

Comment: @egid Digital ATIS is available for some (larger) airports!

Comment: Yeah, I haven't found any online sources for D-ATIS, though, other than fboweb, and I'm not a member so I can't even confirm that.

Comment: @egid ARINC has it, but unfortunately it is a commercial service so we won't be able to use that.

Answer (score 3):

### Implemented!

---

```
!!distance <airport code> <airport code>
```

Great circle distance between two points.

Answer (score 2):

`!!fbo <airport code>`

To list FBOs and phone numbers.

Answer (score 2):

`!!airports <city name/zip code>`

List airports (with codes) near a city.

Comment: It's my plan to allow `!!weather`, `!!metar` and `!!airport` to accept an airport/city name, but this is also a good idea.

Comment: http://www.geonames.org/ could help with this.

Answer (score 2):

### Implemented!

---

The command that I would like to see the most is:

`!!TeachMeToFly`

Free flight instruction from our chat bot "Otto the Autopilot" would be great!

Comment: Discussion started: [Teach Otto to teach people to fly!](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/q/186)

Answer (score 1):

```
!!units 5nm to km
```

You could push this directly to the Unix `units` command, but that would probably lead to injection attacks somewhere along the line.

Comment: There's actually a built-in `!!convert` command - we should be able to add it to that fairly easily.

Answer (score 1):

### Implemented!

---

`!!taf <airport code>`

For the aviation forecast.

Answer (score 1):

Low priority because I'm not sure what we'd use as a data source.

`!!100LL KSAW`

`!!jeta KSAW`

Should return `$6.04` or whatever the price of 100LL / JET-A is at that location.

Comment: Great idea Steve, thanks!

Comment: airnav.com and fltplan.com both have fuel prices, but I don't know if we can access the data or not.

Answer (score 1):

Tying into the `!!taf` command, I'll create a corresponding `!!forecast` command to translate to English.

Similar to `!!metar` vs `!!weather`.

Answer (score 1):

## Implemented!

---

```
!!iaps <ICAO airport code>
or
!!charts <ICAO airport code>
```

Provides a link to the FAA Digital Instrument Approach Procedures for the specified airport.

Answer (score 1):

```
!!aircraft N999XZ
```

Retreive aircraft information, including whether there are any [active liens](http://aerolienslist.com) on it.