# Repository for approach pictures?

Tags: discussion

Is there a repository that should be 'preferred' for specific approach plates?  Since people may have particular questions about one or another is there some sort of macro that can be set up?

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you're thinking mainly of the US here? In theory the definitive reference for plates should be the [FAA site](http://aeronav.faa.gov/index.asp?xml=aeronav/applications/d_tpp) because a) it's the FAA and b) it's free and public (unlike Jeppesen).

Interestingly, [one question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/320/if-there-is-a-misprint-on-an-instrument-plate-is-a-pilot-required-to-comply-wit) already found a difference between those two sources, but I think the FAA plates could still be considered the standard reference for general approach plate questions here. Outside the US the plates may or may not be available freely on line (I know in some countries you have - or had - to pay for them).

As for a 'macro' I'm not really sure what you're thinking of. Something like the [chat bot macros](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156/what-would-you-like-the-chat-bot-to-do) to quickly look up or link to a specific approach? I'll have to defer to more knowledgeable people on that one.

Comment: Yeah, what I mean is a macro of some kind that people can use to just drop a plate into a question instead of finding it themselves - yes I guess this would be US only, unless of course there are good references (indexed) for other countries...

Comment: I agree that the Aeronav site is the right choice. Not sure about how to somehow integrate it with the site, though. If we can somehow come up with a consistent syntax, and test it out with the chat bot, that may be a reasonable starting point.

Comment: We should be able to integrate this into the chat bot. I've favourited the question, and I'll make an issue for it shortly. Just working on another couple of commands for the moment. I'm not sure whether we'd be able to add another icon to the WYSIWYG editor of a question/answer @BretCopeland?

Comment: Wikipedia has a similar feature to generate external links to the Aeronav tpp website. Aeronav uses a pretty strait forward naming convention to define d-tpp url's. [Wiki Doc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:FAA-diagram/doc).

Comment: [Issue #33](https://github.com/dannybeckett/SO-ChatBot/issues/33) created.

Comment: @DannyBeckett Did you see this: http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/a/167/69?