# What is the preferred method for linking official publications that expire regularly?

Tags: discussion

The question [During instrument approach, is an abbreviated racetrack course reversal allowed?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/15286/2143) for completeness links to a now-expired [expired approach plate](http://155.178.201.160/d-tpp/1506/05677R33.PDF). Yes, it is possible to link to the current (at press time) [KFNL RNAV (GPS) RWY 33](http://155.178.201.160/d-tpp/1608/05677R33.PDF), but that creates endless janitorial work that will have the undesired side effect of converting the question to a Community Wiki after so many updates.

For some questions, reference links to IAPs, ODPs, DPs, STARs, Chart Supplement, *etc.* ought to float, *i.e.*, always point to current resources. With other questions such as those that deal with possible mistakes that may be later corrected, for example, static snapshots would be most appropriate.

Aaron may have had a similar motivation behind the [Repository for approach pictures?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/206/2143) meta question. Snapshots are straightforward: convert to raster image, upload, and link that static resource. What is the preferred method for linking always-current official publications?

Comment: The issue here is that unless the *publisher* uses consistent naming, links or some other clear way to get the latest version then there's not much we can do about it, apart from using images as you said. Something similar [already came up](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1569/62) once with the FAA, by the way.

Comment: Auto-conversion to Community WIki has been disabled for a while now (see the [Community Wiki FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/262399)).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My general solution here is not to link to the plate: Take a screenshot of it and upload it as an image with your question/answer instead. (This also has the advantage of being able to draw all over the plate or chart, which I've done a few times.)

That way (a) the link doesn't break, and (b) if the plate changes in the future we have the version that the question/answer were talking about. (Useful if someone asks a question about an NDB approach & the NDB involved later goes away, taking the approach with it: The general answer may still be useful, even if the specific example is no longer relevant.)

Comment: If you didn't need to draw on it or some such thing, another alternative would be to link via the way-back machine or similar.

Comment: @reirab That still relies on the wayback machine as an external dependency -- Granted it's probably not going anywhere (certainly not with the next chart cycle), but the links could still break. The Stack Exchange imgur account can be relied upon to exist "at least as long as Stack Exchange exists" (and if Stack migrates to something else they will presumably pound on the database to fix all the links that will break).

Comment: Good point. Still, it might be a reasonable idea for cases where an image doesn't work well and/or to provide a source link for the image when the source regularly changes.

Comment: Yeah the Wayback Machine would potentially be a sensible option for sites/resources that can't be neatly screenshotted. Then again, https://screenshotmachine.com/ makes it easy to screenshot "websites that don't fit on one page" quite nicely, to create a full-page screenshot that can then be uploaded to the SE Imgur