# Should we include airport diagram or charts in posts?

Tags: discussion

I noted that in some questions or answers, a reference to the airport diagram / approach chart is beneficial. My question is whether we should include an image in the post.

A URL may be dead in the future, or the specific diagram may be updated such that it is no longer relevant to the question. Therefore we should include an image.

However, the chart may be copyrighted or behind a paywall (although I don't think anyone will sue us...).

Comment: URLs are a bad idea, yes -- the AIRAC cycle leads to mass link death on the FAA/NACO side

Comment: Related: [here](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/206/62), [here](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3055/62)

Comment: Don't think NOAA/NACO charts are copyrighted, are they?

Comment: US Gov/NACO charts are not copyrighted. Screen caps of Jepp charts would probably be considered fair use.